# Python script can't change user agent and proxies on Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, user-agent, proxies

Actually, i have a script who start a chrome session (not headless). I want to change and rotate user agent and proxies, with fake_useragent and proxy_randomizer libraries.
I've see on somes topics here how to make this, but not work on my chrome session.
I use chromedriver 98.0.4758.82 and chrome browser 98.0.4758.82, and i don't have any error message on terminal. On "userAgent" string and "proxf" string, user agent and proxy are correctly rotate, i think an error is in argument on chrome option, but i don't know.
Here is my script today:

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from proxy_randomizer import RegisteredProviders
from proxy_randomizer.proxy import Anonymity
import requests

# URL
url = "https://www.carrefour.fr"

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

# Proxies
rp = RegisteredProviders()
rp.parse_providers()
#print(f"proxy: {rp.get_random_proxy()}")
for proxy in rp.proxies:
     proxies     = { "https": f"{proxy.ip_address}:{proxy.port}" }
     #response    = requests.get("http://google.com", proxies=proxies)
prox = rp.get_random_proxy()
proxip = prox.ip_address
proxpo = prox.port
proxf = "https://"+str(proxip)+":"+str(proxpo)
#print(prox)
#print(proxip)
#print(proxpo)
#print(proxf)

# Ouverture Chrome
options = Options()
ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random
print(userAgent)
#options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxf)
driver.get(url)
driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;")
```

Anyone have an idea why my user agent and proxies are not used on chrome session please? I think i have correct requests, but i don't know...
Thanks for help!
Bye

Comment: I do not see any loop that does repeated requests using different headers. You recreate a single dictionary len(rp.proxies) times - but thats all. It will always result in the last proxy ... you should debug your code to see what it does.

Comment: I think "for proxy in rp.proxies:" part is not necessary no? What does you say by "loop"? Loop is necessary ?

Comment: Check your code - your loop does nothing.  You only loop filling a dict that you overwrite again and again until only the last entry is in it.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand what you mean by "your loop". Its only this part of code (for proxy in rp.proxies:)? Or its  complete script code loop?
Actually, this script work same here: define url str, define rp str and parse providers proxies, define random proxy on prox str, and open chrome session with userAgent str defined by ua.random and random proxy on prox str. This code will be work normally no?
Just sorry, because i want to know python code, but im beginner actually.

Comment: `for proxy in rp.proxies: proxies     = { "https": f"{proxy.ip_address}:{proxy.port}" }` is the only loop in the code you show. This loops over rp.proxies - it creates a dict `proxies` that contains the 1st value of  rp.proxies in a string under the key "http" - then it creates another dict and overwrites the current one with the 2nd value, then the 3rd and so on ... until the last value. Then the loop is over and the created dict is used - it will never use any other value then the last from rp.proxies.  this is _really_ basic python ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok now, here is the correct code:

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from proxy_randomizer import RegisteredProviders
from proxy_randomizer.proxy import Anonymity
import requests
from fresh_useragent import UserAgent

def getRandomUserAgent():
    lines = open('UAStrings.txt').read().splitlines()
    return random.choice(lines)
ua = getRandomUserAgent()

prox = rp.get_random_proxy()
proxl = "http://"+str(prox)


options.add_argument(f'user-agent={ua}')
options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={proxl}')
```